# Microstates, molar mass, and degrees of freedom.

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the relationship between the number of microstates and molar mass. The key says choices II and III are correct. If III is true, why isn't I also true? Also, if II is true, why isn't IV true as well?

I think that the greater the number of microstates, the greater the number of DoF. I figured that much out.

Why would NH3 have more degrees of freedom than NO2? Is it because NH3 has more attached atoms than NO2?

Is molar mass just a red herring in the first statement? NO2 has fewer bound atoms than NH3; it seems that the number of bound atoms affects the number of microstates *more* so than molar mass, because in III, where the two species are structurally identical, molar mass comes into play.

So when determining the number of microstates, is the number of attached atoms more important than molar mass?

I can't seem to find any good online resources relating molar mass with the number of microstates and degrees of freedom.

[image]